# Look up values and return value if conditions are met

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Is it possible for an automation which searches for the word "Example" in column B, C and D and Shows Output on Column E in these cases:

```
E2= "100%"  if  "Example" is found in all three columns B2 C2 and D2
E2= "55%"  if " Example " can be found in 2 columns B2,C2 or B2,D2 or C2,D2
E2= "10%"  if "Example " can be found in just one column B2 or C2 or D2
```

This should work on a range from 2 to 1000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you could try:

`=IF(COUNTIF(B2:D2,"Example")=3,"100%",IF(COUNTIF(B2:D2,"Example")=2,"55%",IF(COUNTIF(B2:D2,"Example")=1,"10%","")))`